# App uses Core Data - how to implement a "print report" feature?

Tags: ios, pdf, core-data

My app uses Core Data to store 6 attributes for each entry as well as an image. I have several users asking for a feature where they can print out what they've entered. I can export the core data entries to a .csv file, but what about the images? cvs isn't pretty for the common user. They'd have to pull it into a spreadsheet app (if they have one) and play around with it to make it usable. But there's no way to export images into a .csv file.

What I'd  really like is a way to push a button and have the app generate a report or a .pdf or something that they can email to themselves, or pull out of iTunes and it'll be formatted in rows with the entries, attributes and the images.

Any ideas? Can anyone point me to something that I can pass my core data attributes (6 text strings and an image) and output them to a pretty .pdf or webpage?

Comment: I think sending an email with a link to download the report would be better.  You could also try generating the PDFs on the iPhone, I did a quick google search and there seem to be a handful of libraries out there.

Comment: Yes, but how do you generate/format the report? The first step is actually making the report. Presenting it to the user is secondary.

Comment: I found this post on here: [core-data-print-contents-of-an-entity](core-data-print-contents-of-an-entity) Maybe I can then pass that array to a file. But what is that going to do with the images? Maybe I can pass the array to a web page and then conver to pdf? I guess I'll have to try it out when I get home.

Comment: Oops. Messed up the link on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804773/core-data-print-contents-of-an-entity"

Comment: you generate the report on the web site using PHP, Java, Ruby, ASP .NET, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, it should be fairly easy to create your own extremely simple HTML templating method.

Pick one sample entity and create a HTML page that formats it the way you want.  Replace the actual data from the entity with placeholder text strings that you can search for at run time.  Copy this template into your project.  When the user presses the button, open the template, merge in the actual data, and save the result as a new HTML file or mail message.

If you want something more flexible, try searching GitHub for "HTML templating" or look at http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa/